Status bar text is converted to icons
5 years ago I asked this question:
status-bar-icons
I still haven't found a way to get the in-built Blender icons into the status bar to display the various operator key modifiers while running modal.
Today I came across this post in a feature request:
Writing guideline for the status bar text
What caught my eye was the last comment by a dev before he closed it:

Probably not needed now that the status texts are being converted to
icons.

Does anyone know what this means and how it works?
The docs make no mention on this, well not that I can find...
I've tried a few things but nothing is creating an icon:
'MOUSE_LMB'
"MOUSE_LMB"
\'MOUSE_LMB\'


It's not exposed to API yet. Operators can't define their own status bar keys

@nickberckley, any idea what the dev was talking about then?
